# How to make vertical navigation bar in Opencart v2.0.1.1?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart V2.0.1.1. Please suggest  how to change the default Opencart navigation bar(Horizontal) to the Vertical. With Sub-Categories popping in right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl` remove the `nav id="menu"` tag and all that is inside it.

Then in the admin, go to `System>Design>Layouts>Home` and add the `Category` module to either `Column Right` or `Column Left`, whichever you prefer.

Actually you may need to add it to every route that you want it to appear since the header is called in every template. Experiment and see how it goes.